# What exactly do logTotalScore and logAcoustic Score represent in Sphinx-4 helloworld?

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, sphinx4

I want to slightly modify helloworld.java of Sphinx-4 and use it for pronunciation evaluation.

For this I want to know two things:

1. What do logTotalScore and logAcoustic Score represent. (If possible, please explain with an example.)
2. Does HelloWorld use HMM anywhere?

Comment: Please supply some code (for example, how the logTotalScore and logAcoustic methods implemented). Currently we have nothing to go on.

Answer (score 2):

Like the names, logTotalScore is the combined score of acoustic score (scored against the acoustic model) and language score (against the language source). logAcousticScore is the acoustic score. In helloworld sample, the language score is from the jsgf grammar.

HMM is used (WSJ model, as configured in helloworld.config.xml).